# How to loop through DIV id element to check style None or Block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through DIV id element in order to check the style if its none/block?

**Code to check against**

```js
// The below code can perform that but just once.

if($('#loadingProgressContainer').css('display') == 'none')
{
 console.log("Display = NONE !!!");
}
else
{
 console.log("Display = BLOCK !!");
}
         

//I tried with the below code but not working



while ($('#loadingProgressContainer').css('display') != 'none')
{ 
   console.log("Display = BLOCK !!"); 
}
     
console.log("Display = NONE !!!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbNewStyleWrapper" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="loadingProgressContainer" style="display: block;">
  <div id="loadingProgressElement">
  <p><h1>Test Please...</h1></p>
   <img src="http://www.dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle2/components/com_taxibooking/assets/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif">
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"loop through a div id element"*? There's only going to be one with the given ID, no? Perhaps you could make use of [**`:visible`**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: What do you mean by *"just once"*?

Comment: Do you mean you need to repeatedly check for the element visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to repeatedly check for the element visibility you could use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). This is NOT the best way to do this, but is a quick solution. The second argument of set interval is how often you want the function to run in milliseconds. The code below will run every 3 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   if($('#loadingProgressContainer').css('display') == 'none')
   {
      console.log("Display = NONE !!!");
   }
   else
  {
     console.log("Display = BLOCK !!");
  }
     }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($('#loadingProgressContainer').css('display') == 'none') {
    console.log("Display = NONE !!!");
  } else {
    console.log("Display = BLOCK !!");
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbNewStyleWrapper" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="loadingProgressContainer" style="display: block;">
    <div id="loadingProgressElement">
      <p>
        <h1>Test Please...</h1>
      </p>
      <img src="http://www.dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle2/components/com_taxibooking/assets/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This snippet is only reference if you want to check visibility of your div after certain period repeatdly**

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```
$('div').each(function() {

   /* Check the CSS Display Property and display it in console. */
   console.log($(this).css('display'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('div').each(function() {
   /* Check the CSS Display Property. */
   console.log($(this));
   console.log($(this).css('display'));
});
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.